# Selenium Extent Report Test

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests, extentreports, test-reporting

I have many tests for which I now want to create a test report. I wanted to see how exactly this works. Do I have to write the code for the report for each test individually or is it possible to write it once and link it to each test?
Would anyone have a sample code, how it is structured?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try to add Allure Reports module to your solution:
https://allurereport.org/

Comment: Is that idea fine for you? If yes, please accept my answer.